# Rewrite urls for cdn on http and https

Tags: apache, https, cdn, mod-pagespeed

We are running mod-pagespeed on serveral apache nodes behind a [varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/) wich sits behind an [ngnix](https://nginx.org/) which handles `https`.
So all request arrive apache as `http` but with an extra [x-proto header](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-proto).

PageSpeed works fine on `http` and rewrites urls to the desired cdn domain, yet fails to do so in `https` requests.

The settings:

```
ModPagespeedRespectXForwardedProto on
ModPagespeedDomain mycdn.azureedge.net
ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain mycdn.azureedge.net *mydomain.com
```

where mycdn.azureedge.net is the cdn and anything mydomain.com is my website.

My complete mod_pagespeed config [can be found here](http://pastebin.com/Ge5cN8hB).

If i do set `ModPagespeedRespectXForwardedProto` to `off`, for `https` requests, links are rewritten to the cdn but with `http` as the protocol.

I did set up a local machine (with docker) to test this localy and have the same problem. Thou Pagespeed works fine for http, urls are not rewritten for https. If i use debug filter, the debug information is added even in https requests so Pagespeed is definitively running for both protocols.

I added [the stats_log_global output as a pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/11bsB2Dg) and [the debug log output from the html here](http://pastebin.com/pQzDEePR) as well.

How do i get pageSpeed to rewrite those urls on https requests as well?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear on your domains, as you mention example.net and example.com, but they don't appear in your config. Are you serving come content yourself and some via a CDN?

Have you tried setting `ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain` as suggested in the docs? It looks like you'd need to add the protocol on the front to get the mapping working.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/https_support#map_the_origin

Do you definitely need to rewrite the domain? It seems like mapping the origin would be sufficient.

Comment: example.net and example.com are _examples_.

Comment: ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain is to handle how data that is altered (compression and such) will be fetched, not how domains are rewritten.

Comment: Yes, i do need to rewrite the domain. How would mapping make the end user load data from my cdn?

Comment: OK, I'm still not quite clear what the architecture is. Is everything HTTPS? It only some pages. Does only some content come from the CDN, or all of it? Mapping wouldn't help, but it isn't clear from your question that you weren't having a problem with the reverse proxy.

Comment: Both http and https exist. All content is on our server. if any asset url is called via the cdn, the cdn copies it from our server, caches it and delivers it. My question was and is: "How do i get pageSpeed to rewrite those urls on https requests as well?". Do you thnk the reverse proxy could be an issue for the rewrite process? The domain rewrite process shouldn't be concerned with where the assets are or how to access them right?

Comment: Did you try putting the protocol in front of the domains in the ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain setting? Or can you not do that because some content is http and some https?

Comment: Some content is http and some is https.